# How to turn off interval loop

Tags: javascript

How would I stop this loop? The loop is necessary, I'm just not sure how I stop it when I need to.

```js
setInterval(function(){
        console.log("Loop running");
}, 6000);
```

Answer (score 0):

const interval = setInterval(...

clearInterval(interval);

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clearInterval(intervalId)`

```js
let intervalId  = setInterval(function(){
        console.log("Loop running");
}, 6000);

// on some action

clearInterval(intervalId);
```